# How to remove MELPA repository from package-archives?

Tags: package-repositories, list

I added MELPA stable and MELPA repositories with

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
```

How can I remove one of them from the list so `M-x package-list-packages` does not show duplicate packages? Also, how could I print the list to see if the entry is really gone?

Comment: Why do you add it in the first place if you would not like to have the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `M-x RET customize-variable RET package-archives RET` and you will be shown the customize options page for package archives where you can add or remove entries. After changing, click on `State` button and click on `Save for future sessions`.

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer is correct and i like that it can be used to edit any variable in a visual way. For completion, I will say that, in this case, removing one of the lines with the form `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))` from the `.emacs` file eventually removed its respective repository.

Comment: Yup, this is the more obvious answer, but I wrote my answer so that you would get to use customize options in emacs :) sometimes it's better than adding or removing entries in .emacs or init.el file.